# Logical short-circuit inside a function handle

Tags: matlab, lazy-evaluation, anonymous-function, logical-operators, short-circuiting

I have a function handle that operates on 2d arrays of arbitrary size:

```
R2T = @(DL1,DL2) arrayfun(@(DL1,DL2)...
                 1/(fzero(@(x)fFitObj1(x)./fFitObj2(x)-...
                 DL1./DL2,[minLim maxLim])) ...
                 ,DL1,DL2) - C1;
```

Here's a bottom-up breakdown of what it does:

- `fzero(@(x)fFitObj1(x)./fFitObj2(x)-DL1./DL2,[minLim maxLim])` - This bit looks for a zero of the considered function on the interval `[minLim maxLim]`, where `fFitObj1` and `fFitObj2` are function handles available from before, `C1` is some known constant and `DL1, DL2` are provided.
- `@(DL1,DL2)1/(fzero(...))` - a wrapper for `fzero` that allows `DL1` and `DL2` to be provided from outside.
- `arrayfun(@(DL1,DL2)...,DL1,DL2)` - another wrapper which allows `fzero` to correctly operate element-by-element when `DL1, DL2` are provided as a matrix.
- `R2T = @(DL1,DL2) arrayfun(...) - C1;` - yet another wrapper that allows to provide `DL1, DL2` from outside.

My problem is that sometimes the matrices `DL1, DL2` may contain `NaN` values, in which case `fzero` returns the following error:

```
Error using fzero (line 242)
Function values at interval endpoints must be finite and real.
```

This is why I naturally thought of the available [operations with short-circuiting](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/logicaloperatorsshortcircuit.html), so I tried to incorporate a `any(isnan([DL1,DL2]))` into this so that `fzero` won't even be evaluated if its inputs would be `NaN` - but whatever I try (e.g. a custom-made ternary operator) the `fzero` seems to be evaluated and the code errors.

**The desired result:** I'd like to implement a lazy evaluation of the `fzero` to only occur when the inputs are valid (in this case, not `NaN`), and return `NaN` otherwise as demonstrated in the **Edit** below.

Related resources:

- http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/147044

---

### Edit:

Here's a piece of code that illustrates the problem (MATLAB 2014a):

```
clear variables; clc;

LIM = [0 5];
fFitObj1 = @(x)x.^2; fFitObj2 = @(x)1;
C1 = 100;

[DL1A,DL2A,DL1B] = deal(ones(2));
DL1B(4) = NaN; DL2B = DL1B;

R2T = @(DL1,DL2) arrayfun(@(DL1,DL2)...
                 1/(fzero(@(x)fFitObj1(x)./fFitObj2(x)-...
                 DL1./DL2,LIM)) ...
                 ,DL1,DL2) - C1;
             
R2T(DL1A,DL2A) %//case A, runs fine
%{
// ans =
// 
//   -99   -99
//   -99   -99
%}   
R2T(DL1B,DL2B) %//case B, errors due to NaN
%{
// Error using fzero (line 242)
// Function values at interval endpoints must be finite and real.
// 
// Error in @(DL1,DL2)1/(fzero(@(x)fFitObj1(x)./fFitObj2(x)-DL1./DL2,LIM))
//
//
// Error in @(DL1,DL2)arrayfun(@(DL1,DL2)1/(fzero( .....
%}
```

The desired result, in case B is:

```
 ans =
 
   -99   -99
   -99   NaN
```

Comment: Have you considered using a separate `.m` file instead?

Comment: Yes, I have.. My hunch says that this is too dynamic to be put in an m-file (I may be wrong there, though).

Comment: Well, `.m` files are more flexible than anonymous functions, so it must be possible (the process of capturing variables via arguments may be less elegant, but you can use `if`-`else` as well as `try` `catch`, which would be a huge benefit in this case)

Comment: Putting it all in a regular M-file will be faster and easier to read too. Stop the madness. You could possibly also replace the `arrayfun` with something faster too.

Comment: I understand what you're saying.. Right now I'm trying to find out whether this is possible with function handles.

Comment: Well, it is in fact possible to short-circuit in anonymous functions, but it is difficult for us to find out what is actually wrong with your code, as your example is not a [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). (We don't have `fFitObj1`, `minLim`,...)

Comment: You can put anything you like there, really (e.g. '@()1').. I'll add a runnable example when I'm near a computer.

Comment: There is a happy compromise between a separate m-file and an anonymous function -- a nested function.  The advantage of the nested function is that it can close over the local variables (like `minLim` and `maxLim`) in the current scope, just like an anonymous function can.  But it also can use normal statement blocks, it doesn't have to be just one single expression.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As already [mentioned in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28797788/logical-short-circuit-inside-a-function-handle#comment45870105_28797788): Doing this inline is **madness** and you are much better off using a separate function / `.m` file.

It will be

- Faster
- Easier to read
- Easier to write
- Easier to debug

You could do this for example in a similar way to this:

```
function out = R2TComputation(DL1, DL2, minLim, maxLim, C1)
...%Compute whatever R2T would compute.
```

To get the same interface as your original anonymous function has, you can simply create

```
R2T = @(DL1, DL2) R2TComputation(DL1, DL2, minLim, maxLim, C1)
```

which will capture the current values of `minLim`, `maxLim` and `C1` at the time you create this handle `R2T`.

---

Yet another option would be to use a [*nested function*](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/nested-functions.html) instead of the external one. It would have access to the parent function's variables, yet still be able to use `if`, `else` and all the other basic tools you need. Only downside: It is not meant to be accessed from within other files.

```
... % Main function stuff
     function out = R2T(DL1, DL2)
         if ...
            out = ...
         ...
     end
... % Use R2T ...
```

---

However, for the sake of freedom of shooting oneself in the foot, here is an inline version of `if-else`, which I wrote in the spirit of [Loren's blog post](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2013/01/24/introduction-to-functional-programming-with-anonymous-functions-part-2/) and **I do not recommend using**, as there are hardly any benefits of using a single expression instead of the corresponding `if`-`else` statements.

```
ifelse = @(cond, varargin) varargin{1+~cond}(); %Only for the insane
```

If you want it to do [lazy evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_evaluation), you need to [pass an anonymous function](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2010/10/21/delaying-evaluation-of-function-inputs/) with zero parameters, which `ifelse` will then evaluate (That's what the last two parentheses `()` in `ifelse` are for):

```
ifelse(true, 42, @()disp('OMG! WTF! THIS IS CRAZY!!111'))
```

If you simply wrote the function call to `disp` as an argument to `ifelse` without `@()`, the function would be called before we even access `ifelse`. This is because MATLAB (as most other languages) first computes the return value of the function, which is then passed to `ifelse` as a parameter.

In your case the resulting code would be:

```
R2T = @(DL1,DL2) arrayfun(@(DL1,DL2)...
                 ifelse(~any(isnan([DL1, DL2])), ...
                        @() 1/(fzero(@(x)fFitObj1(x)./fFitObj2(x)-DL1./DL2,LIM)), ...
                        NaN), ...
                 DL1, DL2) - C1;
```

Comment: It also *won't work*, because `minLim`, `maxLim`, and `C1` won't be in scope.  You could use globals (yuck!), or add more parameters (making it incompatible with passing through existing functions that expect a certain signature), but using a nested function would provide most of the benefits with none of the limitations.

Comment: Ok, another option would be to make a separate m function that replaces just the `fzero` and NaN-checking part, since that doesn't require any additional external inputs.

Comment: @BenVoigt: I'm not sure I get what you mean. `R2T` would capture `minLim`, `maxLim` and `C1`. What do you mean wouldn't work?

Comment: Aren't you suggesting moving `R2T` to a separate m-file?  It can't then capture anything.

Comment: Nah, this is [SPARTA](https://ssdl-wiki.cs.technion.ac.il/wiki/index.php/Spartan_programming)!! :)

Comment: @BenVoigt: Yes, this what I would suggest. Creating a `function out=R2T(DL1, DL2, minLim, maxLim, C1)` and then building an anonymous function using: `R2Tanon = @(DL1, DL2) R2T(DL1, DL2, minLim, maxLim, C1)`, capturing the current values of `minLim`, `maxLim` and `C1`. I'll add it to the answer.

Comment: @BenVoigt: Your suggestion of a nested function is also a great idea. It just depends if the OP will want to do this computation across multiple files I guess, which would be the only case where my version is preferable to nested functions.

Comment: (For future readers: knedlsepp's last comment was about a comment of mine which was deleted, since I found and edited into the answer a link to Loren's blog that discusses this topic. My question was "How come `ifelse(true, 42, @()fzero(123,456))` works but `ifelse(true, 42, fzero(123,456))` doesn't?")

Comment: @knedlsepp - Great. I think a more intuitive explanation is that when the argument is an anonymous function, whatever you write there is practically equivalent to a `string` (and therefore has no effect). If there comes a time for it to be evaluated, something like `eval()` or `str2func()` is happening internally.

Comment: @Dev-iL: You are basically right, with the addition that local variables that the anonymous function uses will be copied (captured) to the anonymous functions own workspace.

Comment: @SamRoberts: It was my intention to hide the code to make it more obvious that the solution is not something I would recommend. Don't you agree with using a spoiler here? I don't want to spoil people's programming experience. ;-)

Comment: @knedlsepp My apologies - I didn't realise you'd done that deliberately. I guess I thought spoilers are better used for spoilers, and if you're posting code that you wouldn't recommend, it might be clearer to just say "I don't recommend this". But that's just an opinion - if your styling was deliberate, please feel free to roll back my edit.