# How to invoke short-circuit logical operators in MATLAB as a function?

Tags: matlab, operator-overloading, logical-operators, low-level, short-circuiting

MATLAB operators usually translate into a function form as in the following examples:

- `~A` => `not(A)`
- `A + B` => `plus(A,B)`
- `A(...)` => `subsref(...)`
- `A(...) = ...` => `subsasgn(...)`
- etc.

Now please consider the operators [`&&` and `||`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/logicaloperatorsshortcircuit.html).

The various documentation (1-[doc for or](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/or.html), 2-[doc for and](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/and.html), 3-[the MATLAB Programming Fundamentals ebook](https://www.mathworks.com/help/pdf_doc/matlab/matlab_prog.pdf)), does not shed any light on this, and nor do `help and`, `help or`, `help relop`. 
This also didn't help: `profile('on','-detail','builtin')`.

What I can say is that `|` seems to be redirected to `or()` judging by the following example:

```
>> 1 || [0,0]    
ans =    
     1

>> 1 | [0,0]    
ans =    
     1     1

>> or(1,[0,0])    
ans =    
     1     1

>> 1 && [0,0]
Operands to the || and && operators must be convertible to logical scalar values.
```

**So my question is: assuming it's possible - how can one explicitly call the underlying function of `&&` and `||`?**

(*note: this question deals with the aspect of "how", not "why")*

Comment: I doubt that functional style call of AND could avoid executing the arguments.

Comment: @Dev-iL: if you want a functional form of the [short-circuit operators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation), you'd have to use a language with a [lazy evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_evaluation) model.

Comment: @Amro - You probably know that MATLAB provides some form of that (as demonstrated in Daniel's answer, for example). Nevertheless, I thank you for the insight. BTW - `&&` and `||` are the "living proof" that MATLAB does have lazy evaluation capabilities... The question is why can't we use said MATLAB capabilities for other things as easily?

Comment: [This](http://ideone.com/JtTanj) and `sAND(@() expr1, @() expr2, ...)` is probably as close as it gets.

Comment: @knedlsepp: I'm reminded of [this](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/39735-functional-programming-constructs/content//iif.m) which was presented a few years ago on Loren Shure's blog as part of a [series on functional programming](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/category/functional-programming/) techniques in MATLAB

Comment: @Amro: Yup, I read [Loren's post](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2013/01/10/introduction-to-functional-programming-with-anonymous-functions-part-1/#c8d04efb-1a2d-4c35-afff-dd52e6c660d2) about inline `if`, when the OP asked [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28797788) question. That's why it is quite similar. ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There can't be a function implementing the underlying functionality. Assume there is a function `scor` which implements this operator, then calling `scor(true,B)` would evaluate `B` before calling `scor`, but the operator does not evaluate `B`.

Obviously scor could be defined `scor=@(x,y)(x||y)`, but it will evaluate `B` in the upper case.

/Regarding the comment using function handles, this might be a workaround:

```
%not printing a:
true||fprintf('a')
%printing a:
scor=@(x,y)(x||y)
scor(true,fprintf('a'))
%not printing a:
scor(true,@()(fprintf('a')))
```

Comment: Yes, but why not something like `builtin('&&',a,b)`? Would this also evaluate the inputs right away?

Comment: @Dev-iL: Again, `builtin` is a function, b is evaluated.

Comment: @Dev-iL: There is no functional form of the logical short-circuiting operators `&&` and `||`, and for good reason... The arguments would have to be evaluated before calling such functions, which defeats the purpose of [short-circuiting behavior](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/logicaloperatorsshortcircuit.html#bt_0nai-1).

Comment: Perhaps `builtin('&&',a,@()b)` ?

Comment: @Dev-iL: It seems when you were installing Matlab you were hoping to get Haskell. ;-)

Comment: But that's the thing.... we're dealing with workarounds here... not the actual calls to `||` and `&&`, however they may be realized.... I tend to agree with @Amro 's point. @knedlsepp - I'm just exploring... :P

Comment: btw - just noticed that SO suggests the following [related question on a similar subject](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25913237/is-there-actually-a-reason-why-overloaded-and-dont-short-circuit) which I find very informative.

Comment: (I'm accepting this answer under the assumption that the distinguished Daniel and @Amro don't fit [Clarke's 1st law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clarke%27s_three_laws#Clarke.27s_first_law) :) )

Comment: @Dev-iL Well, Daniel's reasoning in his first paragraph _seems_ to be irrefutable! :-)