# MATLAB equivalent to Python's negative indexing

Tags: python, arrays, matlab, indexing

**Problem:** Depending on the boolean value of `smth`, the array `a` has to be iterated either forwards or backwards. Because of recursion, the first (or last) element has to be treated beforehand.

In Python I can influence the direction an array is iterated through by tweaking the index a bit (*):

```
a=range(2,11,2)

sign=1
os=0

if smth:                
    sign=-1
    os=1

print(a[sign*os])          #*
for k in range(5):
    print(a[sign*(k+os)])  #*
```

Now, as there are no negative indices in MATLAB, I couldn't find a way around doubling the instructions (simplyfied to "print" above) and adapting the indices:

```
a=2:2:10

if smth
    a(1)
    for i=2:5
        a(i)
    end   
else
    a(end)
    for i=4:-1:1
        a(i)
    end
end
```

Is there a way around this, eventually similar to the Python code above? The actual instructions will be much longer, including combinations of multi-dimensional indexing.

Also, in this case, flipping the array after the evaluation of `smth` is not possible.

Answer (score 6):

I think what you're looking for is the keyword [`end`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/end.html). When appearing in indexing expressions, it refers to the last position within an array. You should also remember that in MATLAB it is possible to specify a pre-made vector for loop indices, so it doesn't have to be created "on the fly" using the colon (`:`) operator. Below is an example of how to use this for your needs:

```matlab
ind_vec = 1:5;

if smth
  ind_vec = ind_vec(2:end);
else
  ind_vec = ind_vec(end-1:-1:1);
end

for ii = ind_vec
  ... %// do something
end
```

---

Alternatively you can use a makeshift ternary operator<sup><sub><sup>1</sup></sub></sup> in conjunction with [`flip`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/flip.html) to get the right indices:

```matlab
function out = iftr(cond,in1,in2)

if cond
    out = in1;
else
    out = in2;
end
```

Then you could get the desired result using:

```matlab
ind_vec = 1:5;
ind_vec = iftr(smth,ind_vec,flip(ind_vec));
ind_vec = ind_vec(2:end);
```

---

<sup><sub><sup>1</sup></sub></sup> - Also available as a [function handle](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28798626/3372061).

Comment: The thing I want to overcome is having to write the whole *...do something...* twice. This—if aptly nested—could probably manage that. In the meantime I found a very folksy method of doing this (for any kind of indices, though), what do you think of it?

Comment: @Maasumi - could you please come over to the [MATLAB chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81987/matlab-and-octave) ?

Answer (score 1):

It's not very nice, but this might do the trick,

```
for i=smth*(1:5)+~smth*(5:-1:1)
    a(i)
end
```

Comment: Although FYI I'm pretty sure this will fail if the arrays (`1:5` and `5:-1:1`) are different sizes.

Answer (score 1):

what about (you may replace `5` by the actual length of `a`):

```
if smth
    it = 1:5
else
    it = 5:-1:1
end

for i=it
    a(i)
end
```

Comment: I forgot to state that this doesn't work in the actual code, as the indexes get modified in different ways (i+1, i-2, (i:-2:1,i*2) etc., also depending on `smth`). But that again gives the idea that it's eventually possible to agglomerate all the kinds of modifications into this preceding `if`-statement.

Answer (score 0):

I found another (questionable) possibility:

```
a=2:2:10;
s=smth;
a(5^s)
for k=(5^s-s)*2^~s:(-1)^s:5^~s
    a(k)
end
```

Comment: plaudits  for heading down the "obfuscated code" path :-)